# queue for logging

Tags: c, debugging, logging, buffer

What's the best way to collect debug messages for logging to file in one go on exit.

I am using c and was thinking of using the queue system. Would this be the correct solution.

I don't require a complex solution. All I would need is for the debug log strings to be stored then released for writing to file when called at the end of the program in one go, Any examples of such a routine

Comment: How about using a in memory file or a ram disk? Then, you have no disk access during you programm run, but you log via the file interface.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a very useful solution; I find it invaluable to do things with my app and observe the debug log messages in order to find bugs.  What's wrong with just writing messages to file whenever they are logged, like every one does?

Comment: Why are you doing this, instead of logging as you need? What happens if the program terminates abnormally and you lose information that could help determine, at the very least, what the program thought it was doing at the time?

Answer (score 3):

`fprintf()` etc are already line buffered. So it'll automatically save some disk time for you. If you insist on further buffering, [use](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/setbuf/) `setvbuf()` with `_IOFBF` so that the stream you write on will be fully buffered.

Note that`stdout` is line buffered and `stderr` is unbuffered. Choose the parameters to `setvbuf` accordingly!

**EDIT** As many have noted in the comments to the question,  it makes sense to have it unbuffered only when the stream is either `stdout` or `stdin` But when the stream is a debug file ( which you analyse once the program has exited ) and your program has intensive logging and runs for long time then it definitely makes sense to buffer the streams.

Here is an example which exemplifies the usage of block writes. Normally, all files are block buffered. Now, I shall override this behavior and make it unbuffered using `setvbuf` and lets see how much is the time difference

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen ("new.txt","w+");

    int i =0;

    /* Comment the below line to make fp buffered */
    i=setvbuf(fp, (char*) NULL,_IONBF, 0);

    if ( i )
    {
        printf("Error in setvbuf\n");
    }
    for ( long int i=1000000; i>0; i-- )
    {
        fprintf(fp,"Hello %ld\n",i );
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

With buffering ( ie commenting the `setvbuf` line ) , the following is the output of the command

```
time ./a.out

real    0m0.224s

user    0m0.192s

sys     0m0.020s
```

And without buffering, ( i.e enabling `setvbuf` )

```
time ./a.out

real    0m4.479s

user    0m0.752s

sys     0m3.708s
```

We can see a huge difference of **4.2s**!!

Hope this helps someone trying to learn about buffering and logging.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
#define SIZE_INCREMENT 10

const char **messages = NULL;
int messagesCount = 0;
int messagesSize = 0;

__attribute__((constructor))
static void initializeMessages(void)    
{
    messages = calloc(SIZE_INCREMENT, sizeof(const char *));
    messagesSize = SIZE_INCREMENT;
}

void addMessage(const char *message)
{
    if (messagesCount >= messagesSize)
    {
         messages = realloc(messages, messagesSize + SIZE_INCREMENT);
         messagesSize += SIZE_INCREMENT;
    }

    messages[messagesCount] = malloc(strlen(message) + 1);
    strcpy(messages[messagesCount], message);

    messagesCount++;
}

__attribute__((destructor))
static void logAllMessages(void)
{
     FILE *logFile = fopen("/path/to/log/file/", "w");
     for (int i = 0; i < messagesCount; i++)
     {
         fprintf(logFile, "%s", messages[i]);
         free(messages[i]);
     }

     free(messages);
     fclose(logFile);
}
```